# Cancel and Return in PHP

Tags: php

I have a formular, where you can edit a customers data. Below this there are 2 Buttons "Save" and "Cancel". Saving works fine, but if I click the cancel button, it should close the Formular and go back to the last page, which is the customer overview. How do I realize this?

Comment: Can you please show your code and explain what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need PHP for that, just a bit of Javascript. Try this:
`<input action="action" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="history.back();" />`

Comment: You can also wrap the history.back() with a confirm() so the user can confirm they want to leave and lose any changes.
Another option is to just add a hyperlink (<a>-tag) to the customer overview page.

Comment: @sguetsch It is html, keep it outside <?php ?> tags or it will fail parsing

Answer (score 0):

```
<input action="action" type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="history.back();" />
```

Worked perfectly for this. Only had to end the php section and start it behind the funtion again